# How to set up Spring Security SecurityContextHolder strategy?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using asynchronous methods in my service (Spring 3 `@Async` annotation). And I've got a problem - spawned thread doesn't have security context. Cause of it is Spring Security by default uses `SecurityContextHolder.MODE_THREADLOCAL` strategy for its context holder. But I need to use `SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` strategy.
For the moment I set up strategy in my *AuthenticationSuccessHandler*. But in my point of view it's not a good practice.

So how can I set it up in context configuration file?
Version of spring security is 3.0.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security and @Async](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246428/spring-security-and-async)

Comment: Note that for web applications, this is the wrong question to ask. Using `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` can result in a thread pool containing threads with the wrong security context for async tasks. A better approach is to use an executor that delegates the security context when it runs the task. See here: [Spring Security and @Async (Authenticated Users mixed up)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246428/spring-security-and-async-authenticated-users-mixed-up)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `spring.security.strategy` to `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL`.  You could also have a simple bean that during your web applications startup calls `SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL)` and initialize that value in your context configuration file.

[SecurityContextHolder API](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html)

Comment: Thanks for your tip about simple bean. But I found more convenient solution for me - I added to my security context following code:

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
                p:targetClass="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder"
                p:targetMethod="setStrategyName"
                p:arguments="MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL"/>

Comment: I'm still having no httpRequest.getRemoteUser() with this bean configured.

Comment: Beware of the implications: if using a threadpool, you should also use setTaskDecorator() as explained here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6856#issuecomment-518787966 
I think is is REALLY important.

Comment: @FrancoisMarot Thank you for your thread pool hint! It saved my rear end. With `SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL`, my thread pool sometimes didn't get the user context. With `executor.setTaskDecorator(runnable -> new DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable(runnable));`, it seems to always do.

Comment: @KarstenSilz can you please share sample code of this working? I am having the same issue and I have been unable to get it to work

Comment: I set spring.security.strategy in resource.properties, but no effect. Any idea why?

Comment: @NickWills This is a 14 year old answer - I'm guessing it doesn't work this way anymore

Answer (score 32):

The java config for @viator 's answer if it helps you.

```
@Bean
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean() {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(SecurityContextHolder.class);
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("setStrategyName");
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(new String[]{SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL});
    return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
}
```

Comment: Late comment :-) Is there an advantage to using this over some sort of @PostConstruct somewhere in a configuration class for security?

Comment: I'd have to see an example. Postconstruct won't make a spring bean so I'm not sure how?

Comment: I meant like inside @PostConstruct calling SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(); It's all static so my guess is it would probably work as well. I'll have to give it a shot.

Comment: There's a complete explanation in a great post here   
https://dev.to/spooz/spring-security-and-threads, covering not only @Async but any custom thread

Comment: @hitch.united See this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65353568/1026624

Answer (score 5):

A little bit another solution, like @viator write:

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass"
            value="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="setStrategyName" />
        <property name="arguments" value="MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL" />
    </bean>
```

Working like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Via Java configuration without reflection.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

  @PostConstruct
  public void enableAuthCtxOnSpawnedThreads() {
    SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
  }
}
```

Comment: Used this, but I got burned with `CompletableFuture` because Security context was null and didn't realize it before it was too late.