# Spring Security and Asynchronous execution

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-security

I recently found myself having the same problem Lukasz describes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246428/spring-security-and-async).  While the answer to this question proved helpful and ultimately helped me to solve my problem I was hoping someone may know why `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` does not properly handle `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL`?  Is this problem isolated to `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`?

Thanks!
Ryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, according to [this post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?80370-SecurityContextHolder-propagation-problem-with-thread-pools) in the spring source forum, the value in child threads is set from the parent thread only when the thread is created. If you have a pool of threads for reuse, the value is not set again unless you change it.

I quote from the post

> You seem to want the context of the calling thread (which invokes the
>   executor) to be used instead of the context of the creating thread.
>   This isn't the same as using an inherited thread-local, so that's not
>   the way to go. You would be better to set the context explicitly
>   yourself, or customize the executor implementation to do so.