# Is it/How to provide SecureContext to a Thread from a managed Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-security, alfresco

I want to be able to launch the creation of an Alfresco node Asynchronously to prevent a creation bottneck.

For that I'm trying to use `ScheduledExecutorService` initialized with value 10.

Execution Processed like follow :

from my `UploadServlet` --> (public) `UploadManager#createNodeRef(SOME_PARAMS)` --> (private synchronized) `UploadManager#createNodeRef`(SOME_PARAMS)

Transaction is managed inside `UploadServlet`

**Code :**

```
private synchronized NodeRef createNodeRef(ARGS) {
  //
  // Creation Code using other Alfresco/Spring beans
  //
  return RETURN_VALUE;
}
```

**Async Code (What I'm trying to do)**

```
    private NodeRef makeAsyncNodeCreation(ARGS) {
    final ScheduledFuture<NodeRef> scheduledFuture = nodeCreationExecutor.schedule(new Callable<NodeRef>() {
        @Override
        public NodeRef call() throws Exception {
            // HERE I MAKE THE EFFECTIVE NODE CREATION
            return createNodeRef(filename, type, parentNode, label, kinematic);
        }
    }, MAX_NODE_CREATION_DELAY_IN_SECONDS, SECONDS);

    try {
        return scheduledFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new AsyncNodeCreationException(e);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        throw new AsyncNodeCreationException(e);
    }
}
```

**Then the public method**

```
public NodeRef create(ARGS) {
    return makeAsyncNodeCreation(ARGS);
}
```

**The problem**

I have the following exception

```
net.sf.acegisecurity.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: A valid SecureContext was not provided in the RequestContext
```

**My Question**
Why SecureContext does no more exist within my async call ?

Comment: See this for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246428

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `SecurityContext` is hold by `SecurityContextHolder` in a ThreadLocal Variable (the default strategy) thus the current thread, you need to pass the `SecurityContext` to the Callable because it's running in a different thread and then inject it to it's own ThreadLocal in `SecurityContextHolder`.

I hope this solution applies to Acegi Security :

```
 // Get the SecurityContext hold by the main thread
 final SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();

 final ScheduledFuture<NodeRef> scheduledFuture = nodeCreationExecutor.schedule(new Callable<NodeRef>() {

  @Override
   public NodeRef call() throws Exception {

    // Inject the securityContext 
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);

    // HERE I MAKE THE EFFECTIVE NODE CREATION
    NodeRef noderef = createNodeRef(filename, type, parentNode, label, kinematic);

    // Cleaning...the thread may be recycled
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(null);

    return noderef;

 }
}, MAX_NODE_CREATION_DELAY_IN_SECONDS, SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mohamed was right, the new thread knows nothing about currently authenticated user and a transaction, so you have to set them manually in your thread. In Alfresco Community 6.2 you have to use `AuthenticationUtil` instead of `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` as it returns null, also it is required starting a new write transaction:

```
    final Authentication fullAuthentication = AuthenticationUtil.getFullAuthentication();
    final RetryingTransactionHelper retryingTransactionHelper = transactionService.getRetryingTransactionHelper();

    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(()-> {

        AuthenticationUtil.setFullAuthentication(fullAuthentication);

        retryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(() -> {
            // your code here
            return null;
        }, false, true);

        AuthenticationUtil.clearCurrentSecurityContext();
    },0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```