# Spring @async copy session

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I´m using Spring `@Async` for make an asynchronous request, but problem is that in order to do that request I need "authentication" of Spring security in my `SecurityContextHolder`.

In order to make it works what do you think is the best option to copy the session from one thread to other.

Comment: It is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246428/spring-security-and-async

Comment: What he is doing is what I´m doing right now. Pass the authentication to the async method to be set there. I even rather my approach. It´s more clean and no magic stuff. But the authentication was just one of the possible issues. I´m suffering problems with Hibernate session issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

try to create empty SecurityContext from another thread, then set authentication to that context, then set this context to SecurityContextHolder as a newly created context. You can run it in runnable

Comment: that´s what I´m doing, but I would like a nice mechanism to copy the whole bean session scope.