# Spring Security @Preauthorize and @Async

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-ldap, spring-async

I am having the `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` check methods when I am calling from the UI (It will take around 2 to 3 hours meanwhile session is getting expired) I am geetting the `SecurityContext` as `null`.

Tried with `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Also I tried the following code:

```java
public class CustomThreadPoolTaskExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor{
    @Override
    public void execute(final Runnable r) {
        final Authentication a = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        super.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SecurityContext ctx = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
                    ctx.setAuthentication(a);
                    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(ctx);
                    r.run();
                } finally {
                    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but I'm still getting the same error:

> org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Comment: Did you try [`org.springframework.security.task.DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M1/apidocs/org/springframework/security/task/DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor.html)?

Comment: Yeah tried with the **DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor** getting the same error.

Comment: Tried with the code provided in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214386/get-user-that-runs-an-asynchronous-method

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Executor executor = new DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor(newCachedThreadPool(), getContext());

CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {}, executor);