# Security Context is null with CompletableFuture

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, completable-future

I have a strange issue.
Given this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/randomizer"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public CompletableFuture<String> randomizer(){
        CompletableFuture<String> someString = stringService
                .findRandomByInput("123")
                .thenCombine(stringService.findAnotherRandomByInput("321"), (result1, result2) -> {
                    return applyRandom(result1, result2);
                });

        CompletableFuture<Void> computation = computingService.computeRandomByInput(RandomDto.empty(), "123");

        return someString.thenCombineAsync(computation, (result1, result2) -> {
            combineIt(result1, result2, getCurrentApplicationUser());
        }, taskExecutor);
    }
```

By calling `getCurrentApplicationUser()` i´m acessing spring´s `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` interface.

I have this taskExecutor:

```
@Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(6);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("DmpkApplication-");
        executor.initialize();
        // the following is necessary because of:
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/57434013/7320372
        return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);
    }
```

So the problem is:

I call the above `randomizer` controller like 5 times and by the 6th time, the `getAuthentication()` call is `null`.

Sometimes the first call to the controller yields `null` and all other subsequent calls work.

I don´t know what´s the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix myself.

I renamed the above bean

`public Executor taskExecutor()`

the following:

`public Executor executor()`

Now the issue is gone. I think Spring defines already an `executor` itself. The previous `taskExecutor` was an additional one. But somehow the Spring one `executor` got called which is not a `DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor` by default.

So maybe that is the issue.

Nevermind - now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following steps in spring boot also we need to be careful so as the code is closing the executor service & not creating any memory leaks once context is closed.

Step 1 - Creating a Configuration class like below.

```
@Configuration
public class EnableSecurityCtxForThreadPool {

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(8);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(15);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("async-");
        //executor.initialize(); 
// this is not need as stated above because ThreadPoolTaskExecutor extends ExecutorConfigurationSupport
which again extends InitializingBean which call this method automatically using @Overidded afterPropertiesSet method
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor
            (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor delegate) {
        return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(delegate);
    }
}
```

Step 2 : Create a Utility Class, so that we can get bean of `DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor` instead of Autowiring ApplicationContext inside your code.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(String beanName, Class<T> clazz) {
        return context.getBean(beanName, clazz);
    }
}
```

Step 3 - Create A completableFuture like this, so that all the thread in the pool have security context setup already.

```
CompletableFuture<String> stringCF = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Hello JayZ", SpringUtils.getBean("taskExecutor", Executor.class));
```