# Spring - alternative way to have request context in child thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, http, web

In java application using spring I'm facing situation when I need to create asynchronous REST endpoint for some small data processing.

I.e. current idea is:

- we got request for processing
- as soon as we verify it could be processed we return `200 OK`
- at the same time we create child thread in which processing will run

Child process is used because we need to have Request / Session in that processing thread (because current user should be checked and recorded during processing - due to legacy code it's hard to do before).

I use [solution found on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540466/spring-promoting-request-scoped-bean-to-child-threads-httpservletrequest) and it works like a charm.

However some of colleagues on review regard it "insecure" to enable inherited request context on all thread. Thus I'm looking for other possible approach.

What I tried is to share request attributes to child thread manually:

```java
    var attrs = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    new Thread(() -> {
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attrs);
        // ...
    });
```

This partly works, but only till response is sent in parent thread. After this I get exception with explanation `Cannot ask for request attribute - request is not active anymore!`

I tried to specify that parent's attributes are inheritable - but this doesn't help:

```java
    var attrs = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attrs, true);  // inheritable
    new Thread(() -> {
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attrs);
        // ...
    });
```

*(I got error saying that I have no active request, If I'm not wrong - tried few more similar variations)*

So any further hints are welcome (or explanations of my mistakes). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't, please don't try to extend a requests life over different threads, that will only lead to issues. Instead prepare the data/parameters you need and use that in a thread instead of having downstream components rely on the requests as well (basically the request should be contained to the controller and not venture out of it).

Comment: Thanks for comment. Right, it is how things should be done. We all hate situations when something needs to be "wisely hacked" in order to overcome legacy issues :(