# Java Future - Spring Authentication is null into AuditorAware

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-security, completable-future

This is my scenario:

My app has Mongo Auditing enabled, with a custom AuditorAware which gets the current user from the `SecurityContext`. This works well with synchronous methods, and the current auditor is successfully saved, but I can't make it work properly with `@Async` methods.

I have an async method (`CompletableFuture`) that makes some updates on my Mongo Database. When the `AuditorAware.getCurrentAuditor()` is called, no authentication info exists, and I can't get the current auditor (`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns `null`).

```
@Override
public User getCurrentAuditor() {
   Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

   if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()
                || authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            log.error("Not authenticated");
            return null;
    }

    [...]

}
```

I'm using a `DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(200);
        executor.initialize();

        return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new ItacaExceptionHandler();
    }

}
```

How can I make it work properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring security context is always bound to Threadlocal.

Probabably you may to additionally set MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL for the security context.

```
@Bean
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean() {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(SecurityContextHolder.class);
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("setStrategyName");
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(new String[]{SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL});
    return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
}
```

http://www.ogrigas.eu/spring/2010/04/inherit-spring-security-context-in-child-threads

[How to set up Spring Security SecurityContextHolder strategy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467918/how-to-set-up-spring-security-securitycontextholder-strategy)

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5246585/525036), using `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` will not work when using an Executor that re-uses threads (the inheritance occurs only when creating the thread). However it should work with `DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor`. @s1moner3d are you sure that the executor you showed in the question is actually used? `CompletableFuture` uses the common ForkJoinPool by default.

Comment: @DidierL How can I check this? I am sure that it is instantiated at boot time

Comment: @DidierL I checked and you're absolutely right! It uses `ForkJoinPool`. How can I make it use `DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor`?

Comment: @s1moner3d I guess the simplest is to debug one of the `@Async` methods to see in which thread it runs, or to print `Thread.getCurrentThread().getName()` in that method.

Comment: @s1moner3d it depends on how you create your `CompletableFuture`. Most of the methods have overloads with an `Executor` argument, but if you rely on Spring `@Async` I guess you have a factory that handles their creation so it should be done there.

Comment: I am new of `Future`s. I have the posted `AsyncConfigurer` and I get tasks by `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()`. How can I autowire my `DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor` and pass it to the `supplyAsync` ?

Answer (score 7):

Following the comments on [kuhajeyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40347437/525036), it appears you are not properly using `CompletableFuture` with Spring `@Async`.

If you launch your tasks by using e.g. [`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-), they will be executed by the [common `ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) and not the one you have configured for `@Async`. You could use the overloads that take an `Executor` as argument, but it would not actually benefit from the advantages of `@Async`.

What you should do, instead, is let Spring handle the task execution, and simply return a **completed** `CompletableFuture` like this:

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> someMethod() {
    // do some computation, but return a completed future
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("Hello World!");
}
```

Spring will then execute your method asynchronously in the configured executor while immediately return a `CompletableFuture` which will be completed when your method returns.

If you are using Spring 4.2 or above, [this is supported out of the box](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13128). Otherwise there is a bit of implementation required, but that would be for another question.