# How can I leverage spring-data-jpa auditing (AuditorAware) in asynchronous tasks?

Tags: java, spring-data

Currently, My [`AuditorAware`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/AuditorAware.html) Implementation uses Spring's [`SecurityContextHolder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) to retrieve the current Auditor for saving creation/modification usernames:

```
@Service
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<UserDetails> {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public AuditorAwareImpl(UserDetailsService userDetailsService){
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails getCurrentAuditor() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName());
    }
}
```

This works fine for most operations except for asynchronous tasks executed by Spring batch's [`SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html).

By the time entities need saving, since the [`SecurityContextHolder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/AuditorAware.html) is wiped after the request has been processed, and the `jobLauncher.run(...)` returns asynchrnously, the `AuditorAwareImpl.getCurrentAuditor()` method throws a `NullPointerException` due to a null `getAuthentication()`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.services.AuditorAwareImpl.getCurrentAuditor(AuditorAwareImpl.java:31)
    at com.example.services.AuditorAwareImpl.getCurrentAuditor(AuditorAwareImpl.java:18)
```

So far I have included the request-invoking user as a non-identifying parameter to the Job but don't know where to proceed from here.

***What is a recommended way of leveraging spring's inbuilt auditing when the `SecurityContextHolder` is not appropriate for finding the invoking "auditor"?***

Comment: I am stuff with this problem, any solution yet?

Comment: i meant stuck, not stuff(mistake)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap your [`AsyncTaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/AsyncTaskExecutor.html?is-external=true) in a [`DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M1/apidocs/org/springframework/security/task/DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor.html) which is specially designed for propagating Spring `SecurityContext`. Also you will additionally need to set `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` for the security context.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345643/java-future-spring-authentication-is-null-into-auditoraware

Comment: Thank you. Since I am using the SimpleAsyncTaskExecuter, setting the MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL strategy was enough for me.