# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returns null inside @Async method

Tags: spring, spring-security

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(`) returning `null` when i call inside a `@Async` method. Tried to use `SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` strategy. but it doesn't work

```
<bean
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
      <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder" />
      <property name="targetMethod" value="setStrategyName" />
      <property name="arguments" value="MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL" />
  </bean>
```

used inside applicationContext-security.xml and applicationContext.xml as well

Comment: Please add your Spring Security configuration. Are you sure, that you are logged in?

Comment: Yes, the user is logged in .

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246428/spring-security-and-async and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467918/how-to-set-up-spring-security-securitycontextholder-strategy?

Comment: Did you get any answer for this?