# Intercept all JDBC calls using AspectJ within a request scope and returning as response

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, aspectj, executorservice

I am having trouble implementing a query profiler for my dataservice (Spring boot application) for debugging purpose. Any help would be appreciated.

**Problem statement**:

I need to return all the database queries being executed for a particular endpoint along with response.

**My approach**:

I have created a request scope component and autowired in the aspect, populating the queries in the request scope object and injecting it with the response. I have provided all the files required below.

**Issue**:

Some of the endpoints execute query in multiple threads. I was getting error but was able to fix the errors using `simpleThreadScope`. However I am not able to see any of the queries executed by threads (I can see queries executed outside threads). Could you help me get queries executed inside thread in the response as well?

AspectJ configuration:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <aspectDirectory>aspect</aspectDirectory>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.10</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Compile and weave aspects after all classes compiled by javac -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class QueryProfilerAspect {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(QueryProfilerAspect.class);
    private static String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm:ss.SSS";
    private static String QUERY_PROFILER = "QueryProfiler";

    @Autowired
    QueryProfile queryProfile;

    @Pointcut("(call(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations.query*(..)) && args(query,params,..))")
    public void anyJDBCOperations(String query, Map params) {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping) || @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping) || @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping) || @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping)")
    private void anyGetPutPostDeleteMappingMethodPointCut() {
        // pointcut
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    private void anyRequestMappingMethodPointCut() {
        // pointcut
    }

    @Around("anyJDBCOperations(sqlQuery, params)")
    public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, String sqlQuery, Map params)
            throws Throwable {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Object output = jp.proceed();
            long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

            DataSource dataSource = ((JdbcTemplate) ((NamedParameterJdbcOperations) jp
                    .getTarget()).getJdbcOperations()).getDataSource();

            if (params instanceof Map && !params.isEmpty()) {
                logger.debug("inside instance of MAP!!!! ::param {}", params);
                sqlQuery = replaceMap(sqlQuery, (Map<?, ?>) params);
            }

            queryProfile.getQuery().add(sqlQuery);
            logger.info("Intercepted Query is::: {}", sqlQuery);
            return output;
    }

    @AfterReturning(value = "anyRequestMappingMethodPointCut() || anyGetPutPostDeleteMappingMethodPointCut()", returning = "returnVal")
    public void anyPublicControllerMethod(JoinPoint jp,
            ResponseEntity returnVal)
            throws Throwable {
            HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                    .currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

            QueryProfile qp = new QueryProfile(queryProfile);
            qp.setRequestURL(request.getRequestURL().toString());
            qp.setHostName(getHostName());

            Object responseBody = returnVal.getBody();
            if (responseBody instanceof ResponseDTO) {
                List<QueryProfile> profileList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (((ResponseDTO) responseBody).getMeta().get(QUERY_PROFILER)
                        != null) {
                    profileList.add((QueryProfile) ((ResponseDTO) responseBody)
                            .getMeta().get(QUERY_PROFILER));
                }
                profileList.add(qp);
                ((ResponseDTO) responseBody)
                        .addMeta(QUERY_PROFILER, profileList);
            }
    }
}
```

Request Scope object:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "simpleThreadScope", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class QueryProfile {
    private String hostName;
    private String requestURL;
    private Long duration;
    private String time;
    private String dataSource;
    private List<String> query = new ArrayList<>();

    public QueryProfile() {
        //Default constructor
    }

    public QueryProfile(QueryProfile qp) {
        setHostName(qp.getHostName());
        setRequestURL(qp.getRequestURL());
        setDataSource(qp.getDataSource());
        setDuration(qp.getDuration());
        setTime(qp.getTime());
        setQuery(qp.getQuery());
    }

    public String getHostName() {
        return hostName;
    }

    public void setHostName(String hostName) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
    }

    public String getRequestURL() {
        return requestURL;
    }

    public void setRequestURL(String requestURL) {
        this.requestURL = requestURL;
    }

    public Long getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Long duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(String dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public List<String> getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(List<String> query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
}
```

`SimpleTheradScope` configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MainConfig implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        if (beanFactory instanceof ConfigurableBeanFactory) {

            logger.info("MainConfig is backed by a ConfigurableBeanFactory");
            ConfigurableBeanFactory cbf = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory;

            /*Notice:
             *org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope
             * !=
             *org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope
             */
            org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope simpleThreadScope = new SimpleThreadScope();
            cbf.registerScope("simpleThreadScope", simpleThreadScope);

            /*why the following? Because "Spring Social" gets the HTTP request's username from
             *SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() ... and this 
             *by default only has a ThreadLocal strategy...
             *also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3468965/923560 
             */
            SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
        }
        else {
            logger.info("MainConfig is not backed by a ConfigurableBeanFactory");
        } 
    }
}
```

My thread executor class: in the class, I am creating a list of Runnable tasks (that call DAO method to execute queries) and calling below class method to execute them in parallel.

```
public class ThreadUtils {
    protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(ThreadUtils.class);

    public static void executeInParallel(List<Runnable> runnableTasks) {
        ExecutorService executorService = new DelegatingSecurityContextExecutorService(
                Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5),
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext());

        CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = runnableTasks.stream()
                .map(task -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, executorService))
                .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
        CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
```

My response is as:

```
"data":{},
"meta": {
        "QueryProfiler": [
            {
                "hostName": "xxx.xx.com",
                "requestURL": "http://localhost:7010/abc/5",
                "duration": null,
                "time": null,
                "dataSource": null,
                "query": [
                    "SELECT * FROM table1",
                    "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table2 WHERE abc = 1 AND def = 2"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to my problem by ditching the request scope object and implementing `InheritableThreadLocal`. This variable has the property of delegating the context to its child thread as well. so using a `InheritableThreadLocal` variable in my aspect and adding queries to the variable, I was able to inject the variable while returning the response.

Along with the above code, I added the following code to make it work:

```
private static InheritableThreadLocal<QueryProfile> queryProfile = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();
public static QueryProfile getQueryProfile(){
    if(queryProfile.get() == null){
        queryProfile.set(new QueryProfile());
        logger.info("Profiler is null. Setting with new value");
    }
    return queryProfile.get();
}
public static void setQueryProfile(QueryProfile qp){
    queryProfile.set(qp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Spring Boot DataSource Decorator** for tracing database calls. You can integrated it with **P6spy**. P6Spy is a framework that enables database data to be seamlessly intercepted and logged with no code changes to existing application.

https://github.com/gavlyukovskiy/spring-boot-data-source-decorator

https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy

This framework is well defined and you don't need to do anything with application.

Comment: I dont need to log the querries. With my implementation i am able to log all the queries even those executed by thread. However i am not able to capture those queries in a request scope object and send it as part of a response. Any help with that?

Comment: You should use Spring HandlerInterceptor then, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor rather AOP.

Comment: I don't think I can intercept the database queries executed with this handlerInterceptor. Can you provide a sample code?