# Spring Session with JDBC | Principal is null

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-jdbc, spring-session

I use Spring Session with JDBC and Mysql.
The Spring Security Login is successfully but the principal name is null.

Does anyone have an idea, whats the mistake?

Files:

application.yaml:

```
  session:
    store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
      table-name: SPRING_SESSION
```

Configuration:

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UsersRepository.class)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/sources/*").anonymous().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/public/*").anonymous().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().
                loginPage("/login").
                loginProcessingUrl("/app-login").
                usernameParameter("app_username").
                passwordParameter("app_password").
                permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().
                accessDeniedPage("/error403");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the database table: 
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmKvK.png)

The pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sandbox</groupId>
<artifactId>TestApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**UPDATE 03/18/19**

I can't change the Security strategy. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KniR2.jpg)

**UPDATE**

If I add the following Bean to my Security configuration, the principal_name in the database is no longer null. Now there is the username of the logged in user.
BUT after each site reload, a new session is created, so the user can't say logged in.

```
@Bean
public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver(){
    return new HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver("X-Auth-Token");
}
```

Comment: add pom.xml codes

Comment: Paste your UserDetailsService code to the question

Comment: Why are you working around Spring Boot (judging from adding all the `@Enable*` annotations. Also where is the code you use to print this line (physically in  your code that is).

Comment: Please see the update..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I had to implement the interface Serializable to my User class. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your credentials are getting erased after logging in. You can prevent that but password you won't find from `Principle` or `SecurityContext`. Try the below code in the above config file:

```java
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.eraseCredentials(false);
    auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
```

**UPDATE**

Add the following bean and see the result:

```java
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

Also please add **pom.xml** content to you question.

**UPDATE**

Add these lines to your pom if you are using Thymeleaf:

```java
<properties>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.11.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.3.0</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    <thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version>3.0.4.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Now the main part, you config file:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UsersRepository.class)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    <strike>@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }</strike>


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.eraseCredentials(false);
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/sources/*").anonymous().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/public/*").anonymous().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().
                loginPage("/login").
                loginProcessingUrl("/app-login").
                usernameParameter("app_username").
                passwordParameter("app_password").
                permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().
                accessDeniedPage("/error403");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Finally the controller:

```java
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/check")
public String check(Principal principal) {

    System.out.println(principal.getName());
    return "ok";
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but without success. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @Tom you can accept the edit to your question and add the updated codes.

Comment: Unfortunately, your updated answer has not changed anything. :(

Comment: @Tom check the updated answer. remove the strike part from your config file

Comment: I replaced my configuration with your answer and removed the strike. But without success :/

Comment: added login form

Comment: @Tom Just get rid of `jstl`. That an old tech and it has no official support. Better switch to Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring 3 then this might help you to getName of User

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method = RequestMethod.method)   
public String showCurrentUser(Principal principal) {
      return principal.getName();
}
```

---

OR changing the `SecurityContextHolder MODE` may help you. [Refer Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#securitycontextholder-securitycontext-and-authentication-objects)

---

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/", ""})
    public String start(Principal principal, Model model) {
        if(principal.getName()!=null)
        {
            //your code
        }
        else
        {
            //your code
        }    
        return something;
    }
```

Comment: `Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        System.out.println(principal);`

**Output:**

    `User{id=0, email='null', password='null', firstName='null', lastName='null', active=false, roles=null}`

Comment: How can I change the SecurityContextHolder Mode?

Comment: @Tom SecurityContextHolder.YOUR_MODE will change the mode. updated answer doesn't help you?

Comment: I‘m tring to test this. But where I have to put these line in? Which file? The Controller where I want to display the principal?

Comment: @Tom Yes, you can use it in controller, refer the updated answer

Comment: Yeah, but I mean, in which file I have to put `SecurityContextHolder.YOUR_MODE`

Comment: @Tom Refer the Link in answer and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467918/how-to-set-up-spring-security-securitycontextholder-strategy

Comment: Yeah, but this is null. (See the Link after my Security Configuration)